# match multiple partial strings from string in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So here I have 2 tables.

```
ring    layer1  layer2  output
12      45      46      bingo
12      34      75  
13      23      47  
14      23      34      nice_work
14      12      15  
14      45      23  
14      67      89      wow
25      90      124 
67      76      341 


ring    whole_string    value as output
12      23_45_12_78_46  bingo
12      78_89_23_45_90  great
13      23_89_90        awesome
14      45_78_23_45_34  nice_work
14      88_86_85_12     cool
14      67_89_111       wow

what I need is: value as output from tbl2 if
1. tbl1 ring = tbl2 ring
2. tbl1 layer1 & layer2 values must be present in tbl2 whole_string
```

Can someone help me with excel formula?

Thank you...

I tried using a for loop. It takes a whole lot time.

Comment: Can I assume that only one line matches the criteria or is it possible that there are several matches? If several: Which one should be used?

Comment: Yes. You can assume that only line matches the criteria because even if there are multiple matches, only one output will be shown - and that is perfectly good with me...

Comment: Well, no. If there _might_ be multiple matches, the formula would be different, because it has to be taylored to take the first match only and not produce fake results because of multiple matches. I'll try to build a formula that can handle multiple matches, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

[image]

Formula in `D2`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($H$1:$H$7,AGGREGATE(14,3,($F$2:$F$7=A2)*(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("_"&B2&"_","_"&$G$2:$G$7&"_")),1,""))*(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("_"&C2&"_","_"&$G$2:$G$7&"_")),1,""))*ROW($F$2:$F$7),1)),"")
```

Entered as array formula through: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Drag down...

Comment: This is absolutely wonderful! Since I am using this in a macro, how can I work the Ctrl+Shift+Enter?

Comment: You mean you use it through Evaluate? In that case no need for array, vba recognise it as such.

Comment: say.. Range("D2").Formula = "=your formula"......how to work Ctrl+Shift+Enter here?